# Unable to call trigger on formula field

Tags: trigger, formula-field

I have one trigger on custom object(A) and another object is lookup(B) for the first object

And i written one formula field on object A with one field on object(B)

Whenever i change the field on object(B),it will update on object(B).

In that case it is unable to call the trigger as object update.

Can any body help me.

Answer (score 6):

Formula fields changes can't invoke trigger.
Those are dataBase-calculated field and value on it is equation you put there, not String that is displayed.

If you want catch this change you have to create trigger on parent object and there manage any changes on child objects.

Answer (score 2):

Value of a formula field will be calculated at run time which may not invoking a trigger. Also as you are explaining, you are updating Object B. It won't fire up the Object A update trigger for a formula field change. Because it's not an update for the Object A. It's just a runtime displaying value change.